# How to obtain my local IP and Port which is behind a nat during a udp socket session?

Tags: sockets, udp, port, nat

I was doing a nat hole punching program and I was wondering is there a way to obtain my local port? I tried using "bind" function which seems to bind the Public port,not my machine`s port.

In Nat, I know private ip:private port ----mapped--> public IP:public port, what I wanna know is private port so that I can listen on it for data arrival and do my own stuff about them..Hope made myself clear enough

Comment: What framework or library are you using?

Comment: @Phil, developing under ubuntu..POSIX I think

Answer (score 1):

`bind()` only works on the local machine.  When you have a machine running behind a NAT, calling `bind()` on that machine bounds the machine's private IP/Port, not the NAT's public IP/Port.  So `bind()` followed by `getsockname()` gives you the private port you are looking for, and then `listen()` starts listening on the bound private IP/Port.

To discover the NAT's public IP/Port, you have to either query the NAT itself using uPNP or SNMP, or query an external site that hass to pass through the NAT, such as http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp, http://iplookup.flashfxp.com, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too clear to me what you want to achieve, but I'll try to explain it to you.

In order to traverse a NAT, you must send a datagram from "inside" to "outside". Then the NAT stores the association and the outside taget can answer.

In the implementation I just tested, the NAT maps the port number 1:1 (useful beause port number might be relevant in the protocol).

Nevertheless, as soon as you have sent the first datagram or you have bound to the null address and the null port, you can call `getsockadress()` and will obtain your real internal address and port.

Your communication partner should use `recvfrom()` in order to get knowledge about the source of the packet. There you have the "external" data where the NAT can be found.